# subscribe based on date in meteor

Tags: meteor, subscribe

I'm kind of new to web development and I became a fan of meteor because of the way it lets me do cool stuf really easy. I have been toying around with the parties example and I have added a date attribute for the parties. I would like to only subscribe the client to parties that have not yet expired.

Essentially where datenow < partydate.

I find myself stuck in writing the correct subscribe code as I only find documentation on how to subscribe based on database attributes and not based on comparing the date of the party with the current date.

Meteor.subscribe("parties"); --> I think this is the part of the code on the client that I need to edit.

I really hope somebody could show me in the right direction on writing the correct subscribe code.

Comment: what is the "date of the party" if not a database attribute?  It sounds like you will need to remove 'autopublish' and write your own 'publish' function.  If you don't have much data you also could just change your template and continue to use 'autopublish'.

Answer (score 0):

The client subscribes to what the server is willing to send to them.

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
  Meteor.subscribe("parties");
}
```

The server filters data the client shouldn't have, typically for security reasons. You wouldn't want passwords or private information being published. Any client can open up the console and browse the full data set that was published to them.

```
if(Meteor.isServer){
  Meteor.publish("parties", function(){
    return Parties.find({date: {$gt: Date.now()}});
  });
}
```

If you want clients to be able to see both expired parties and non-expired parties, you would publish the whole set from the server, then filter it on the client in a template helper.

```
if(Meteor.isServer){
  Meteor.publish("parties", function(){
    return Parties.find();
  });
}
if(Meteor.isClient){
  Meteor.subscribe("parties");
  Template.templateName.allParties = function(){
    return Parties.find();
  }
  Template.templateName.activeParties = function(){
    return Parties.find({date: {$gt: Date.now()}});
  }
}
```